# UICollectionView not bouncing when pulling down

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, large-title

I have the following function which I call in ViewDidLoad;

```
func setUpNavigationBar() {
    guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else { return }
    navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.title = "Feed"
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
}
```

The CollectionView bounces when scrolling to the bottom perfectly fine.  However, when pulling down from the top index sometimes the collectionView doesn't bounce.

I have bouncing enabled vertically.

Problem Solving: I have removed this function and without the large title the collection view bounces fine.  I can get the collectionView to bounce with large titles only when I scroll very slowly & in the simulator.  When using the device I get this abnormal behavior.  Anyone else encountering this? Anything wrong with my code?

testing on iOS 11.2 iPhone7 Device with XCODE 9.2

Many thanks as always.